# mysqli separated class calling from an ajax request returns empty error

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, mysqli

I have to perform some queries in my php Wordpress plugin. So I created a seaprate class file in which I store the logic behind.

```
class Table{

static $host = 'localhost';
static $db_name = 'somedb';
static $db_username = 'someuser';
static $db_password = 'somepass';
private $table;
private $fields;

public function __construct($table, $fields){
    $this->db_name = $this->db_name;
    $this->host = $this->host;
    $this->db_password = db_password;
    $this->db_username = db_username;
    $this->table = $table;
    $this->fields = $fields;

}
public static function query($table, $fields){
    $mysqli = new mysqli(Table::$host,Table::db_username,Table::db_password,Table::db_name);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
        return "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $fields = implode(",", $fields);
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT" . $fields . " from " . $table);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    $result->free();
    $mysqli->close();
    return $rows;
}
```

}
?>

Then I call it from a php file like this:

```
$zips = Table::query("GeoPC_MA", array('city','zip'));
```

I'm calling this last file from an ajax request, the result is an 500 error. However I get nothing in the developer console log.

I thought maybe this is related to the way I am implementing the Table class.

Help me please

Comment: You should apache error logs

Comment: Also `$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT " . $fields . " from " . $table);` see space after `SELECT` or you will get `SELECTcity,zip from `

Comment: You're vulnerable to injection, especially when the call looks something like this: `Table::query('foo', [' * FROM user; -- ']);`

Comment: Thank you so much for your apache log trick insanebits. The problem was in the static variables when I called them, forgot to put the $ sign. 
Please Elias how can I secure my code against injections in PHP?